# Polymer:2.0- How to upgrade all polymer hybrid elements in one go?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

How can i upgrade all elements like paper input paper button in one go so that i don't have to upgrade each element using bower?
I've updated paper-input using

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-input#2.0-preview
```

but do i have to use this for all elements individually?
thanks in advance

Comment: i think that you can rename all polymer elements in bower.json for example from `"PolymerElements/app-route#^0.9.0"` to `"PolymerElements/app-route#2.0-preview"`  and then run in cmd `bower update`  this should work . bowert can inform you about some conflicts, but it will tell you what to do. I didn't test it yet so it's better to make new folder/branch